# How can I delete time-stamped folders if one has already been created that day?

Tags: cron, delete, timestamp

Folders are created every time I (re)boot.

They have the format below: (the time will always vary)

```
.mozilla_2019_01_08_08:02
.mozilla_2019_01_09_20:16
.mozilla_2019_01_10_01:16
.mozilla_2019_01_10_18:12
```

Here, I want to be able to delete the folder .mozilla_2019_01_10_18:12 when it is created as an earlier one already exists on ..._2019_01_10. Better would be to stop it being created, i.e. if one has already been created that day.

I can't use cron @daily or specific times as I never know how often or when the computer will be (re)booted.

How can I do this in an existing script please?

Here is my script:

```
##!/bin/bash
##
# COPY .mozilla FOLDER AND LEAVE LAST 10 COPIES (1 per day?)
#                                                                                                                
sleep 30
#  
if [ -e /home/david/nas-backups/mozilla/ ]
  then
    cp -a /home/david/.mozilla /home/david/nas-backups/mozilla/
    mv /home/david/nas-backups/mozilla/.mozilla /home/david/nas-backups
    /mozilla/backups/.mozilla_$(date +%Y_%m_%d_%H:%M)

# Show result of copy message
    export DISPLAY=:0 && zenity --info --title "Backup Information Box"
    --text=".mozilla Backup Finished

    Backed up to:
    /nas-backups/mozilla/backups/" --width=600 --height=200

## Working on how to keep only first copy per day ##

# Limit to last 10 alphabetical copies (courtesy of @Vijay)
    cd ~/nas-backups/mozilla/backups
    total=$(ls -1A|wc -l); remove=$((total - 10)); rm -rv $(ls -1vA|head
   -n $remove)


# Show folder so I can manually delete extra daily copies
    nautilus /home/david/nas-backups/mozilla/backups

else

    export DISPLAY=:0 && zenity --info --title "Backup Information Box"
    --text=".mozilla backup FAILED

    - nas-backups either not mounted or not availeble" --width=450
    --height=150
fi
```

Comment: Maybe posting the entire contents of the "existing script" could help people help you.

Comment: Who creates those folders? I don't have anything like that on my system.

Comment: @user68186 I have tried mv -n and --no-clobber but the first backup (say .mozilla_2019_01_11 ends up with another .mozilla (no date) inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## One backup per day: Don't create more backups if one exists for today

Add a condition that checks if a backup **folder for today does not exist**. If there is no folder for today then only the `cp` and `mv` will be executed.

Note the `*` at the end of the second folder check. This allows for the time stamp at the end of the folder name, as you have done.

Here is the code fragment:

```
##!/bin/bash
if [ -d /home/david/nas-backups/mozilla/ ]
  then
  if [ ! -d /home/david/nas-backups/mozilla/backups/.mozilla_"$(date +%Y_%m_%d)"* ]
    then
      echo "No backups found for today: Making one"
      cp -a /home/david/.mozilla ~/nas-backups/mozilla/
      mv /home/david/nas-backups/mozilla/.mozilla ~/nas-backups/mozilla/backups/.mozilla_$(date +%Y_%m_%d_%H:%M)
    else
      echo "Backup folder for today exists. No backups will be made today"
  fi
fi
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Many thanks. I was looking at it from the wrong end - parsing existing filenames. Your solution is great  (and logically obvious) - thank you.